# How I could pass user data from back to frontend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express

I made a YelpCamp clone ony with node and EJS but I'm trying to convert to a Node-React project and was working until I try to list a specific user... To get the SHOW route of a User I need to get the route "/users/:id", also I need to react to know which user is logged in to check if he is a admin or not to show an edit and delete buttons. However, the React don't know which id to send to the request...

How could I set this id on the client side? I'm using passport-local and passport-jwt to handle login/register. I know that I can use this token for something like this, but I'm not sure how I can do this!

I don't wanna make this post dirty, so I'll link to my files on github:

1 - [Auth.ts](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/server/src/middlewares/auth.ts)

2 - [UserModel.ts](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/server/src/database/models/user.ts)

3 - [UserController](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/server/src/controllers/index.ts)

4 - [Routes.ts](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/server/src/routes/index.ts)

5 - [Register.tsx](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/web/src/pages/Register/index.tsx)

6 - [Login.tsx](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/web/src/pages/Login/index.tsx)

7 - [User.tsx](https://github.com/Mdsp9070/yelpCamp/blob/reactTS/newVersion/web/src/pages/User/index.tsx)

Comment: Please, if you need more information or explanion, please, say to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know about useContext and Context API, so the answer is: search about useContext hook and how do you create a Context on React without Redux!

Initial link: [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)